# c program. what does the error mean below

Tags: c

```
||=== Build: Debug in 78 pp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

||In function 'main':|

|3|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'int'|

|8|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has 
type 'int' [-Wformat=]|

|9|error: 'big' undeclared (first use in this function)|

|9|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it 
appears in|

|11|error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function)|

|19|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|

||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){ 
   int n,num,int i; 
   printf("Enter the values of n: ");
   scanf("%d",&n); 
   printf("Number %f",1); 
   scanf("%d",big); 
   for(i=2;i<n;i++){ 
       printf("Number %df: ",i); 
       scanf("%d",&num); if(big<num) big=num; 
   } 
   printf("%d",big); 
}
```

Comment: It means that your program has syntax errors. Since you haven't shown us your program it is hard for us to say anything beyond what is contained in the error message. Is there any reason that you included the error message but not the code?

Comment: will i give put the code John Coleman?

Comment: `format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int'` how is that cryptic?

Comment: `'big' undeclared `, `'i' undeclared `...what's so tough?

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int n,num,int i;
  
  printf("Enter the values of n: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
 
  printf("Number %f",1);
  scanf("%d",big);

  for(i=2;i<n;i++){
    printf("Number %df: ",i);
    scanf("%d",&num);
 
    if(big<num)
      big=num;
  }  
  printf("%d",big);
}

Comment: [Take a look here](http://ideone.com/McYDLi)

Answer (score 1):

**Error1:**
expected identifier or '(' before 'int'

The declaration of variables n, num and i is buggy. I think you put a , instead of ;
So replace with

```
int n,num;
int i;
```

or

```
int n, num, i;
```

**Warning2:**
format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

%f implies it expects float, you have passed 1 (int). So replace with6

```
printf("Number %d", 1);
```

or even

```
printf ("Number 1");
```

since it is a constant.

**Error3:** 
'big' undeclared (first use in this function)

Big is not declared. So add `int big;` (assuming it because you scanned with %d). Another issues which will come up later is that you passed int where int* is expected. So replace the scanf call with

```
scanf("%d",&big);
```

**Error4:**
'i' undeclared (first use in this function

Will be solved with resolution of Error1.

**Warning5:**
control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

`main` is declared with return type int but doesn't return anything

Add

```
return 0;
```

at the end to signify successful termination of program. Replace 0 with any another error code if program doesn't exits successfully.

Comment: brother Ajay Brahmakshatriya can you list down the name of the error please which are present in the program.

Comment: I have added the error message with the error numbers. This should help you correlate.

Comment: brother i need the list of the errors and the names of the error.i have attached the code below.    #include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int n,num,int i;

  printf("Enter the values of n: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  printf("Number %f",1);
  scanf("%d",big);

  for(i=2;i<n;i++){
    printf("Number %df: ",i);
    scanf("%d",&num);

    if(big<num)
      big=num;
  }
  printf("%d",big);
}

Comment: I have added you code in the question itself after indenting it. If you can accept the edit, please do. And I don't understand what do you mean by "list of errors". All the errors you have mentioned in the question itself. And errors don't really have names. Even if they did, I don't see how it would be relevant.